# Error tkVideoPlayer: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _core: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having a problem when I run this code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkVideoPlayer import TkinterVideo

root = tk.Tk()

videoplayer = TkinterVideo(master=root, scaled=True, pre_load=False)
videoplayer.load("users/algo/color.mp4")
videoplayer.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

videoplayer.play() # play the video

root.mainloop()
```

It gives me this error

```
File "d:\Documentos\Trabajo-proyectos\databases\aplicacion.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tkVideoPlayer import TkinterVideo
  File "d:\Documentos\Trabajo-proyectos\databases\env\lib\site-packages\tkVideoPlayer\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tkVideoPlayer.tkvideoplayer import TkinterVideo
  File "d:\Documentos\Trabajo-proyectos\databases\env\lib\site-packages\tkVideoPlayer\tkvideoplayer.py", line 1, in <module>
    import av
  File "d:\Documentos\Trabajo-proyectos\databases\env\lib\site-packages\av\__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from av._core import time_base, library_versions
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _core: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.
```

Please, someone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You must delet al av carpets 'av', 'av.libs' and 'av-9.1.1.dist-info'.
Then you install av and start woking.

```
pip install av
```